# Updating list without breaking the code

Tags: c#, list

However, I ran into another issue. Since it updated my list I need figure out how modify the list without breaking my code. suggestions?

What I am trying to do is update my list to send an error message if the action can't be applied to actions and remove actions that do not meet criteria.  So basically if it isn't a code 40 or 45 then remove them from the list and send an error message if the code is 40 or 45.  I don't know if I can clarify my question any further.  I am still new to programming.

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateActionSelected();

        ValidateCleared(actionsChecked);

        if (String.Equals(ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(), "XXX YYY") || String.Equals(ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(), "XXX ZZZ"))
            {
                reqEffectiveDate.ErrorMessage = "";
            }

            if (ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedValue == ActionTypes.XXXYYY ||
                ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedValue == ActionTypes.XXXYYYDenial ||
                ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedValue == ActionTypes.XXXzzz)
            {
                ValidateXXXYYY(actionsChecked, ddlActionsAndDocuments.Text);
            }

            if (ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedValue == InsuranceActionTypes.WWW ||
                ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedValue == InsuranceActionTypes.YYYZZZ ||
                ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedValue == InsuranceActionTypes.YYYWWW ||
                ddlActionsAndDocuments.SelectedValue == InsuranceActionTypes.YYYWaived)
            {
                ValidateCertificate(actionsChecked, ddlActionsAndDocuments.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ValidateCleared(List<xxCaseEntity> actionsChecked)
    {
        foreach (xxCaseEntity ACTIONyy in actionsChecked)
        {
            if (ACTIONyy.XXStatusCode == 40 || ACTIONyy.XXStatusCode == 45)
            {
                DisplayErrorMessage("FR Action Cannot Apply to " + ACTIONyy.CaseIdentifier);

                actionsChecked.Remove(ACTIONyy);

            }                
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: We have no idea what you're asking. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **and** [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please rewrite your question to actually include a question, and also post all relevant code. For instances, there is no explanation what `actionsChecked` is, or what your `ValidateActionSelected()` does. If those are not relevant, remove them. Please check the link @johnnyRose posted on how to write a proper question.

Comment: None of us have any idea what "how modify the list without breaking my code" means.  That statement is far too vague to be actionable.

Comment: `foreach (xxCaseEntity action in actionsChecked.Where(action => action.XXStatusCode == 40 || action.XXStatusCode == 45).ToList())
    {
        DisplayErrorMessage("FR Action Cannot Apply to " + action.CaseIdentifier);
        actionsChecked.Remove(action);
    }`

Comment: Or, if you don't need to display the error message, you can just have a single line in your `ValidateCleared` method: `actionsChecked.RemoveAll(action => action.XXStatusCode == 40 || action.XXStatusCode == 45);`

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove items from a list as you're iterating over that same list.  One technique is to make a new list, and then iterate over the new one.

```
var toRemove = new List<xxCaseEntity>();

foreach (xxCaseEntity ACTIONyy in actionsChecked)
{
    if(ACTIONyy.XXStatusCode == 40 || ACTIONyy.XXStatusCode == 45)
    {
        toRemove.Add(ACTIONyy);
    }
}

foreach (var item in toRemove )
{
    actionsChecked.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Technically you don't even have to create a separate list variable, you can just do it in the `foreach` condition by calling `ToList()` on the list you're iterating over (because `ToList()` returns a new list): `foreach (xxCaseEntity ACTIONyy in actionsChecked.ToList()) { if (someCondition) actionsChecked.Remove(ACTIONyy); }`

Comment: `RemoveRange` doesn't work with a list the way `AddRange` does. `actionsChecked.RemoveAll(condition);` would probably work, though.

Comment: This has helped some.  Of course, it opened new issues.  But thank you.